# Getting error while reading swagger JSON from localhost

Tags: jax-rs, swagger-ui

I am using Spring 3.2.3 + restEasy 2.2.1 + jBoss 7.1.1 Final & swagger jaxrs-2.10-1.3.8.jar . I had a problem fetching list of operations. Here you can see my swagger index page
[image: My Application's swagger index page]

Is there anything missing from configuration code? 
Here is my web.xml

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:beans.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Auto scan rest service -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/rest</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
     <servlet-name>DefaultJaxrsConfig</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.config.DefaultJaxrsConfig</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>api.version</param-name>
         <param-value>1.0.0</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
         com.iana.services.AppInitialiser
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Rest-service class

```
package com.iana.services;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.iana.domain.Employee;
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.Api;
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse;
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.ApiResponses;


@Path("/employees")
@Api(value = "/employees", description = "Endpoint for employee listing")
public class UIIARestService {

    @GET
    @Path("/users/{id}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Returns all employees", notes = "Returns a complete list of employees.", responseContainer = "array", response = Employee.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successful retrieval of all employees", response = Employee.class), @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal server error") })

    public Response getUserById(@PathParam("id") Integer id)
    {
        Employee user = new Employee();
        user.setFirstName("vipul");
        user.setSurname("Chauhan");
        return Response.status(200).entity(user).build();
    }


}
```

Pojo class :

```
package com.iana.domain;

import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;

@ApiModel
public class Employee {

    private String firstName;

    private String surname;

    private int employeeNumber;

    @ApiModelProperty(required = true)
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @ApiModelProperty(required = true)
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    @ApiModelProperty(required = true)
    public int getEmployeeNumber() {
        return employeeNumber;
    }

    public void setEmployeeNumber(int employeeNumber) {
        this.employeeNumber = employeeNumber;
    }
}
```

bean.xml

```
    <!-- Swagger providers -->
   <bean id="apiDeclarationProvider" class="com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiDeclarationProvider" />
   <bean id="resourceListingProvider" class="com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ResourceListingProvider" />

    <!-- Swagger API listing resource -->
   <bean id="swaggerResourceJSON" class="com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResourceJSON" />


    <!-- this scans the classes for resources -->
   <bean id="swaggerConfig" class="com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig">
     <property name="resourcePackage" value="com.iana.services"/>
     <property name="version" value="1"/>
     <property name="basePath" value="http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest"/>
     <property name="title" value="Petstore sample app"/>
     <property name="description" value="This is a app."/>
     <property name="contact" value="apiteam@wordnik.com"/>
     <property name="license" value="Apache 2.0 License"/>
     <property name="licenseUrl" value="http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"/>
     <property name="scan" value="true"/>
   </bean>
```

POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.iana.rest.api</groupId>
  <artifactId>MobileRestAPI</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>MobileRestAPI</name>
  <description>MobileRestAPI</description>
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss repository</id>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <log4j.version>1.7.7</log4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.GA</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.scannotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>scannotation</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Swagger -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
          <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId>
          <version>1.3.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Other libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>oro</groupId>
            <artifactId>oro</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>RESTfulExample</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Does it work if you add "getters" to your POJO Employee class? It may need those to correctly create the json.

Comment: Yes, when I hit from browser http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/employees/users/1 it shows me correct response. like : {"surname":"Chauhan","firstName":"vipul","employeeNumber":0}